# I Cannot match Jquery Ajax data string from the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am checking if  username exists live from the database if it is the username is not available, the response is Inavailable and vice versa. Am getting this response successfully but I cannot match this response string so that I display different details to the user. This is my Jquery Ajax function

```
var dataString = 'user_name=' + username;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_scripts/checkUser.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {    
        if(response=="Available")
        {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            alert("The server data matched"); 
        }
        else if(response=="Inavailable") {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
            alert("The server data did not match"); 
        }
    }
});
```

I cannot match the server resposne. Kindly assist me i am beggining to learn jquery ajax

Comment: plz paste your PHP code.

Comment: Your closing tags are not matching for if(response=="Available")

Comment: please make sure the if looks like `if(...) {...} else if(){...}`

Comment: While Edit Your code You missed `}`.
Check that you don't have script errors.

Comment: alert(response) see what you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check what answer you get from your server :

```
success: function(response) {    
   console.log(response);
   if(response=="Available"){  
      ....
```

The test `if(response=="Available")` will not be true if the server's response contains trailing spaces or linefeeds - a common PHP "bug" : extra spaces after a closing tag are sent in the response ...

If you can afford the effort, I would advise you to have your server return a Json response :

```
//PHP (server side) :
... code ...

$response = new stdClass();
$response->available = $usr != null; //insert correct test here
// add other data if needed :
// $response->userName = $usr ? $usr->Name : "";
// ...

header('Content-type: application/json')
echo json_encode($response);    

//Javascript (client side) :
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "ajax_scripts/checkUser.php",
  data: dataString,
  cache: false,
  dataType: 'json', // <- add this option
  succes: function(data) {
    //with "json" dataType, data will be a regular javascript object
    //built from the server's response
    if (data.available) {
        alert("is available");
    } else {
        alert("not available");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens Some cases Solution is trim your response and match it Try the bellow code. I just used the jquery trim $.trim();

```
var dataString = 'user_name=' + username;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_scripts/checkUser.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {    
        if($.trim(response)=="Available")
        {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
            alert("The server data matched"); 
        }
        else if($.trim(response)=="Inavailable") {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
            alert("The server data did not match"); 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You can also check ajax_scripts/checkUser.php page for blank space

Answer (score -1):

Your: response=="Available" should be like this:

```
response.responseText == "Available"
```

Comment: Have you ever take a look at jQuery's "The jqXHR Object"?

Comment: I know the jqXHR object, but the `success` callback isn't using it in that case. `response` will automatically hold the value of `jqXHR.responseText` if the response was text (or HTML or similar)